# FilterSet on JSONField field in DRF ListAPIView using django_filters always return the same result

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

i want to make an API request in Django Restframework like 
http://localhost:8000/apis/services/?page=1&name=2

**The model**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Service(models.Model):
   name = JSONField(default=dict)
```

**The APIView**

```
class DashboardServicesAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Service.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_class = ServiceFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Service.objects.filter(vendor__company=self.request.user.userprofile.company)
```

**The FilterSet**

```
class ServiceFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="name", 
lookup_expr='icontains') 
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = [ "name"]
```

**Filter backend in settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
.
.
.
```

querying with filter querystring is not working the same result is always returned. 
Any help on what i missed dealing with JSON?

Comment: add backend like     filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)

Comment: i added filterbackend in settings.py

Comment: the same result is returned even the filter query params is set in querystring

Comment: @NwawelAIroume were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need add `filter_backends` to integrate `django_filter` with `drf`

```
class DashboardServicesAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Service.objects.none()
    serializer_class = ServiceSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_class = ServiceFilter

    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,) 

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Service.objects.filter(vendor__company=self.request.user.userprofile.company)
```

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html

> The django-filter library includes a DjangoFilterBackend class which supports highly customizable field filtering for REST framework.

Comment: it is not filtering with the query string set in url